# Hiding html elements 

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I'm attempting to hide the links for edit and destroy actions in the view unless the user has logged in using http basic auth. I've attached my files below. Thanks

View https://gist.github.com/1272716
Controller https://gist.github.com/1272712

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save/store the authenticate result, and then render conditionally in your view.

**Controller**:

```
protected

def authenticate
  @authenticated = authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user, password|
    user == "x4556d4s" && password == "fd55sas64x"
  end 
end
```

**View**:

```
<%= link_to "New Link", :controller => :links, :action => :new %>
<table>
<% @links.each do |link| %>
  <tr>
    <td> <%= link_to '+', up_link_url(link), :method => :put %> <%= link.points %> <%= link_to '-', down_link_url(link), :method => :put %> </td>
    <td> <a href=  "<%= link.url %>"> <%= link.title %></a> </td>

    <% if @authenticated %>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', link, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_link_path(link) %></td>
    <% end %>

  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```